# How can i have a webpage layout that doesnt move when the browser window is re sized

Tags: html, css

I am new to this but i cant seem to get a clear answer on this what do the majority of websites do for their web page layout not to move everywhere when browser is being re-sized.

Comment: Please give more data as to what you mean.  (At least a link to an example of a site that does what you're talking about...)

Comment: It's a setting in html.  I can't remember what it is.  It's in any basic html book.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to give a `width` and `height` in `px` to your HTML elements.

See [this example](http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/shrbG)

Otherwise, they will change relatively to the browser size.

(By the way, I don't know your intentions, but it is considered a bad thing to do that, because it makes your site not responsive to different screen sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

<div style="margin:0 auto; width:980px; height:650px; background-color:#cccccc;">

Add your website content inside this div

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Websites usually set the `height` and `width` of `div`s with percentage instead of pixels. This allows the elements to resize if the page is resized.

So you can do:

```
.html{ height:100%; width:100%;}
.div {float:right; height:25%; width:30%}
```

This will resize the div as the page is resize but it will stay floating on left and not move anywhere.